# Adding custom styles to the react-styleguidist library

Tags: css, reactjs, sass, react-styleguidist

I'm trying to create project documentation using the [react-styleguidist](https://github.com/styleguidist/react-styleguidist) library. However, I have a problem. 
Well, in the project I did reset the unit rem to use multiples of 10px, not 16px.

Everything works great, but I did it at the root of the app styles. Stylegudist does not see it. How can I add such a line to docs library?

`html {font-size: 62.5%; / * Now 10px = 1rem! * /}`

Or make it other way. I don't want to put rem reset to each of my component styles.

Cheers,
Daniel

Comment: Styleguidist [allows inheritance](https://github.com/styleguidist/react-styleguidist/blob/08486758c87ded1f97e14dcef10ef89c9f186389/src/styles/setupjss.js#L27-L33) of `font-size` and some other props, so it's supposed to work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Based on the suggestion of @ArtemSapegin, I found [this repository](https://github.com/styleguidist/react-styleguidist/blob/master/examples/customised/styleguide.config.js), which turned out to be very helpful! I hope that it will solve someone else problem in the future!

This is how looks my `styleguide.config.js`.

```
module.exports = {
    template: {
        head: {
            links: [
                {
                    rel: 'stylesheet',
                    href: 'https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:400,600'
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    theme: {
        fontFamily: {
            base: '"Montserrat", sans-serif',
            fontSize: '62.5%'
        }
    }
};
```